# Login not displayed

Tags: support, firefox, login

I just switched over from using Chrome to using Firefox. I am able to login to all the other StackExchange sites (including this one), but for some reason when I login on stack overflow, it tells me that it is logging me in, but then returns to the main page with no login displayed. I attempted clearing my cache and restarting the browser, but to no avail. The process goes as follows:

Before clicking login:

[image: Before clicking login]

After clicking login: [image: after clicking login]

After redirect:

[image]

Does anyone have any advice or explanation?

Comment: what is your firefox's version ?

Comment: @Lucifer 16.0.1

Comment: same problem for me..in firefox!

Comment: Sometimes login doesn’t work with AdBlock Plus extension in Firefox enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, Firefox. We love Firefox.

This is stupid, but: try clearing your browsing *history*.

Let me know if this doesn't work and we'll try something else.

Comment: Aha! Thanks.... Why the heck did that work?