# Log in problems on Firefox

Tags: bug, login, firefox

I am facing a problem with Firefox when logging onto my Stack Overflow account.  I click on "log in," then I choose "connect with Facebook."  But after that, nothing happens, except for the redirection to the main page.  If I try to log in again, a message displays on the top of the page telling me that I am already connected.

Notice: this problem did not exist on Chrome in my case.

This is the picture of my case:

[image]

Comment: Disable all add-ons/extensions/plugins you have in Firefox. 99% the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a caching issue: when the "Welcome back" message appears, you have been logged in. When you are shown the home page, though, it is still the old one.

If this happens again try clearing your browser's cache and hard-refresh the page.

Comment: i cleared the browser's cash and  hard-refresh the page but nothing changed .

Comment: OK, are you behind a proxy? It could also be that.

Comment: i don't think so ,i am using the default configuration of Firefox.and i changed from system proxy to without proxy , but the same problems.

Comment: A very long shot: can you confirm that you are using the same browser for logging in and browsing? I see a lot of mixed User Agents in the logs?

Comment: because i can not logging onto  my Stack Overflow account with Firefox , i am using now Chrome.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, your colleague Anna wrote [multiple](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow/165469#165469) [times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152249/login-not-displayed/152250#152250) that clearing the browser history (not the cookies or cache) might help, for Firefox.